# How to set Environment variable for Oracle JDBC thin driver

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

After installing Oracle 11g R2 on my system, I set the environment variable as following:

```
variable Name :CLASSPATH 
variable Value :E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar
Variable name : ORACLE_HOME
varaible value :E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar
```

When I run the program using testpad and in command prompt the error comes as follows :

> Error: Could not find or load main class test

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: This error is concerning your actual program, not the jdbc library. What is the full command line you are using to run your compile java program?

Comment: Please post your code and the Java command you are using to run it

Comment: @Simon: how would the code ever be relevant if the JRE already can't find the class?

Comment: The name of the class is kind of crucial: it it's not 'test', then that would explain the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java looks in the classpath for all classes. You've however set the classpath to a single fixed JAR file which is the JDBC driver itself. This JAR file surely doesn't contain your own `test.class` file. Provided that your `test.class` is available in the current working directory, you should have added the current working directory `.` to the classpath.

```
.;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar
```

Note that the paths in the classpath are semi colon separated in Windows and colon separated in *nix.

Alternatively, you could also just control the classpath during execution by the `-cp` argument. This way the environment variable will be ignored altogether.

```
java -cp .;E:\app\JamesPJ\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar test
```

To avoid the tedious work of re-entering the whole command everytime, put it in a `.bat` or `.cmd` file and execute it instead.